# Eclipse: change JDK for all projects in Workspace

Tags: java, eclipse, development-environment

I have received a whole bunch of Eclipse Projects as a ZIP-File. I imported all of them into my new Workspace dedicated for this Task. They are all preconfigured from the other Dev's Workspace. In general I don't mind, so i do not have to setup every one of these Plugin-Projects.

What i do mind is that each and every Project is set to run with a specific JRE from the other guys installation (which I obviously don't have). Is there a convenient Way to change all the Projects in my Workspace to the Workspace default JRE?

I am really not looking forward to right click on every of these ~30 Projects and change it manually.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @arundeep chohan, this only sets the new default JRE. Since all the Projects are configured to use (non existing) "Alternate JRE", it wont solve the problem

Comment: If they are not Maven or Gradle projects, you can change the `.classpath` files accordingly using a shell/batch or Ant script.

Comment: @rootkonda The `eclipse.ini` file is to run Eclipse. The JREs/JDKs to use can be configured in _Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs_.

Comment: Thanks @howlger - this is what I was looking for. The `<classpahtentry kind="con" {...}` needs to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are not Maven or Gradle projects, you can change the `.classpath` XML files accordingly (`<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/..."/>`) using a shell/batch or Ant script. Then do a refresh (e.g. by selecting all projects and hitting <kbd>F5</kbd>) so that Eclipse is aware of the change.